# Use the SamsungSharpSans font

Tags: fonts

i want to use the SamsungSharpSans font on my website,

I downloaded the font and tried it but not working

Here is my code :

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: SamsungSharpSans;
  src: url("https://sabercathost.com/dmYM/SamsungSharpSansBold-Bold.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: SamsungSharpSans;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url("https://sabercathost.com/dmYM/SamsungSharpSansBold-Bold.ttf");
}
</style>

<h1 style="font-family: SamsungSharpSans;font-weight:bold;">
Samsung galaxy S8 plus
</h1>
```

Take a look at the example here :

https://jsfiddle.net/n9pb0m84/4/

I want to use for a page that will contain samsung phones,

Thanks,